# viewWillAppear not fired up from UITabBarController in 4.3 but works fine in 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5, ios-simulator

Yes, I know that it's not a good idea to call UITabBarController via

```
[self presentModalViewController: animated];
```

I have custom UITabBarController with hidden original TabBar and my own TabBar. I use this controller to choose for example song as in iTunes - by singer, by album, by something else. Then when user select one from any tabs I dissmiss this modal view controller and return to main view.

I started developed this with simulator iOS5 and all was fine - viewWillAppear was fired up in all my tabs tableviewcontrollers which I called from tabbarcontrooler [self setSelectedIndex:X];

But then I tried to run my code in 4.3 simulator and device and discovered viewWillAppear never fired up in my tabs at all.

How can I fix this? thx

**Update:**  I use `[self presentModalViewController: animated];` to call new `UIViewController *controller`, where I initiate UITabBarController and place it's view as subview. `[controller.view addSubview:myTabBarController.view];`

Answer (score -2):

In your `UIViewController`, add the following :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   [myTabBarController viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: I'll try, but I afraid that in case of iOS 5 my view will recieve viewWillAppear twice then.

Comment: Well, let me know if it is the case, we'll think of another solution